# Percentage of digits in n that are even

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

[Question 7 from Lab 3](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/fa14/lab/lab03/#q6) of [Berkeley's CS61A course](http://cs61a.org/) says:

> The following examples of recursive functions show some examples of common recursion mistakes. Fix them so that they work as intended. [...]
>
> ```
> def even_digits(n):
>     """Return the percentage of digits in n that are even.
>
>     >>> even_digits(23479837) # 3 / 8
>     0.375
>     """
>     if n == 0:
>         return num_digits / num_evens
>     num_digits, num_evens = 0, 0
>     if n % 2 == 0:
>         counter += 1
>     num_evens += 1
>     return (even_digits(n // 10) + num_evens) / counter
> ```

As per the assignment, below code is suppose to solve this problem, recursively (MUST not be non-recursive).

```
def even_digits(n, count_even = 0, count = 0):
    """Return the percentage of digits in n that are even.

    >>> even_digits(23479837) # 3 / 8
    0.375
    """
    if n == 0:
        return count_even / count
    if (n % 2) == 0:
        return even_digits(n // 10, count_even + 1, count + 1)
    else:
        return even_digits(n // 10, count_even, count + 1)
```

Is this code readable? Can we improve this solution?

Comment: Why does it have to be a recursive solution? Solving this non-recursively looks much more logical.

Comment: Because the assignment says so.

Comment: @skull are you new to codereview?

Comment: Can you quote the assignment (or link to it), please? Also, the example seems wrong: the correct percentage is 37.5%, not 0.375%.

Comment: @GarethRees this is the [link](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa14/lab/lab03/#q6)

Comment: That link goes to question 6, but surely this is question 7. I've edited the post for you, but you have asked a lot of these questions, and surely you know the drill by now.

Comment: The solution proposed in the lab has the same problem of division by 0 (fails when input is 0)

Comment: I am not expert of Python, but when I try the program interactively, the '/' operator perform the integer division, so the result is always wrong for me (I do no get a real number, but constantly 0). Is an error in my version of Python, an error due to my scarce experience on Python, or another error of the program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a serious error in your code. If the function is called as `even_digits(0)`, then it causes the following error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

since in the first `if` you divide by `count` which is `0`.

So, before improving the code, you should check if it is correct.

**ADDED:**

**THE CASE OF `n = 0`**

It is interesting to understand what should be the result in case the input (that is `n`) is 0.

The problem is labeled as:

> Percentage of digits in n that are even

and the natural interpretation is:

> Percentage of digits in **the decimal representation of** n that are even

So, what result should give the function when provided with the value 0? I argue it should be 1, since *every decimal representation of* 0 has only zeroes as digits, so it has a 100% even digits.

Comment: Sorry, Is this the right [solution](https://github.com/shamhub/paradigms_using_python/blob/master/even_digits.py)?

Comment: @Renzo I'm not convinced this is a bug, since the fraction of even digits in the number is undefined.

Comment: @overexchange Don't use `assert` for input validation, since it is removed when the `-O` flag is used.

Comment: @Veedrac Do I need to use try-catch for input validation?

Comment: You could apply the same solution as @TheBlackCat

Comment: @Veedrac, your comment is interesting, but, even if you can say that the number of zeros to be used in the decimal representation is undefined, the percentage of *even* digits is 100%. I changed the answer to add my argument.

Comment: @Renzo After some thought, this answer makes sense. I'll run with it.

Answer (score 4):

Overall it is good.  I would probably clarify that `n` is an integer (this won't work with floats) in the docstring.  I would probably either document `count_even` and `count` or change them to `_count_even` and `_count`.  I would also comment the three cases.  I was able to figure it out, but it took me a few moments.

Also, `0` is `False` in python, so you don't need to explicitly test for `== 0`.

However, I think this would be better as a loop.

```
def even_digits(n, count_even = 0, count = 0):
    count = 0
    count_even = 0
    while n:
       count += 1
       if not n%2:
           count_even += 1
       n //= 10
    return count_even/count if count else 1
```

**Edit**: I change the `return` line (last line) to handle the division-by-zero case

Comment: Always love the tail recursion eliminated.

Comment: @TheBlackCat, the same error that I described in my answer is present in your answer (division by 0).

Comment: @Renzo  I fixed it

Comment: @TheBlackCat Shouldn't it return 1 is case of 0 input? After all, the only digit (in normal representation) of number 0 *is* even.

Comment: @Cthulhu Good point, fixed again.

Comment: don't you mean `if not n%2:`?

Answer (score 2):

`even_digits()` doesn't feel right as the function name.  I would not expect a percentage being returned from that function.  Maybe a count? Perhaps a collection of the individual even digits?

Don't use `else` after `return`.

> ```
>     if (n % 2) == 0:
>     return even_digits(n // 10, count_even + 1, count + 1)
> else:
>     return even_digits(n // 10, count_even, count + 1)
> ```

```
if (n % 2) == 0:
    return even_digits(n // 10, count_even + 1, count + 1)

return even_digits(n // 10, count_even, count + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a count method:

```python
def percent_even(number):
    try:
        number = int(number)  # Check the number is an integer
    except ValueError:
        return None           # Return None if number is not a valid integer
    number = str(number)      # Make the number a string (for count)
    if number:
        evens = [str(even) for even in list(range(0,9,2))]       # Generate a list of even digits as strings
        count = sum([number.count(digit) for digit in evens])    # Count the number of each digit
        percentage = (float(count) / len(number)) * 100          # Calculate a percentage
        return percentage
    else:
        return None        # Return None if the string was empty
```